# Complex way of getting an usable array from set of strings

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, string

I'll try to explain this the best way possible.

I have a set of logs stored in my database. I need to process through those logs which are not quite good stored (in a very inefficient way).

I'll show you the table first:

[image: Table]

So, these sentences in the `value` column need to be broken into usable pieces so I can list the appropriate information separately to my users.

The pieces of information I need to gather from that column:

- Action type (ban, warn, kick, jail and fine)
- The person who issued the action (ie. Scotty)
- The amount of money fined in case the action was *fine*
- Reason of the action

With this collected information, I need to display it *separately* in tables to the user. Bans should be listed in one separate table, warns on their own and so on and so forth.

**How a table would look like for each case:**

```
<h2>Bans</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Issued by</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Reason</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>THE NAME OF THE ISSUER</td>
        <td>DATE AND TIME</td>
        <td>THE REASON</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<h2>Fines</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Issued by</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Reason</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>THE NAME OF THE ISSUER</td>
        <td>DATE AND TIME</td>
        <td>THE REASON</td>
        <td>THE AMOUNT</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Bans, warns and jails should have the same table structure, only fines differ a bit with the *Amount* column.

## How I'm gathering the information

Well, I'm obtaining the information from the database in a simple way, with this method:

```
public function obtain_player_adminlog($player_id)
{
    global $samp_db;

    $player_name = $this->get_pname_by_id($player_id);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM adminlog 
        WHERE value LIKE '%" . $player_name . "%'";
    $result = $samp_db->sql_query($sql);

    return $samp_db->sql_fetchrowset($result);
}
```

I understand that this function is not a foolproof function, but this is the best I could get. The methods used in the query are from phpBB DBAL which is irrelevant to the question.

The returned array with this data would look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [entryID] => 5
            [value] => AdmWarn: {FFFFFF}Scott_Parker has unbanned player Dave_Meniketti.
            [entryTime] => 2013-10-24 00:49:56
            [tickcount] => 4577394
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [entryID] => 11
            [value] => Fine: Scott_Parker has been fined $25039 by Scotty, reason: test test
            [entryTime] => 2013-10-24 00:52:02
            [tickcount] => 4703416
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [entryID] => 12
            [value] => Ban: Scott_Parker has been banned, reason: Third warning (last from Scott_Parker)
            [entryTime] => 2013-10-24 00:52:11
            [tickcount] => 4712439
        )

)
```

---

## To sum it

1. I need a foolproof way to obtain the information from the database
   as it can be easily fooled with the MySQL `LIKE` clause if the name
   is repeated twice for example (ie. `Array[2]`).
2. I need a way to
   split the information based on the action and list it on different
   tables.

To me, this looks like a very complex task and there is no way I can think of a way to solve this. I've been stuck on thoughts on how to achieve this for days - no luck.

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: So are you just asking how to effectively parse the value entry?

Comment: Exactly. That's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you're saying, I'd just use regular expressions! I'll walk you through the parts, but you should really think about [learning more about them in general](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html).

1. First we should break up the list by first word using `(.+?):`. `preg_match("/^(.+?):/", $input_line, $output_array)` will give you an array where the second value is your first word.
2. Then you throw it into a `switch` statement based on that first word, directing it to further processing.
3. Then you make regexes based on the expression. If it's a fine (I chose this because it looks like the most complex), you'd do something like: `preg_match("/^.+?: (.+?) has been fined (\$\d+) by (.+?), reason: (.+)$/", $input_line, $output_array)`. That will give you an array that looks like this: `[0] => Fine: Scott_Parker has been fined $25039 by Scotty, reason: test test, [1] => Scott_Parker, [2] => $25039, [3] => Scotty, [4] => test test` (for some reason SO didn't like this as normal code).
4. You can dump your arrays by type into a parent array using `array_push`, then you just loop over them using `foreach` to generate your page!
5. You could actually just deal with producing the html in that switch. Since you know the array that's coming out, make your template happen then. So for the example in #3 (and your comments), you could do something like `$fineHTML = <tr><td><?=fineArray[3]?></td><td><?=fineArray[5]?></td><td><?=fineArray[4]?></td><td><?=fineArray[2]?></td></tr>`. Then you just push `$fineHTML` to an array, which you loop over with `foreach` to display on the page.

Also as for your MySQL question, [you can use regular expressions there](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html), too.

Comment: I'll try it the way you explained and then report back. Thanks for the response.

Comment: You could just use `array_push` to add the date to the end or `array_unshift` to add it to the beginning. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php

Comment: I've managed to get the data into an array that looks like this: http://pastebin.com/WqtU59vG ... How should I display data in a table correctly? I'm quite confused? Should I rename the inner array keys to strings? I've tried quite some ways, but the information keeps multiplying itself which is confusing me. I'm quite sloppy when it comes to arrays.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I accepted your answer - You were really helpful!